# What is procedure to let set path in wordpress?

Tags: paths

I have installed a plugin called **jsmol2wsp**. Now I have a cif and many kinds of file in which I have to upload this files in the wordpress and set the path according to [link](http://jimhu.org/wp-content/plugins/jsmol2wp/help.htm). I have set the path according to the instruction.

For example I have updated the pdb file in which the command goes like this `[jsmol acc='caffeine' type='mol']`. I have exactly followed these instruction . Still the error in the jmol window is appearing as in the [link](https://energymaterials.org/cztse-06/).

What mistake I have done and what is the error?

Comment: Why nobody is answering?

Comment: Do you have `caffeine.mol` uploaded.

Comment: yes, I have uploaded caffeine.mol

Comment: Then try `[jsmol acc='caffeine' type='mol' fileurl='http://path_to_file']`   and replace `http://path_to_file` with url to your  `caffeine.mol`

Comment: I have did the same , still I couldnt find any output except the blank jmol window

Comment: Please check this link now..https://energymaterials.org/cztse-06/).

Comment: Please answer me .

Comment: Your plugin is outdated, update it and contact plugin support if the problem is not solved.

Comment: Plugin is not the problem . I cant identify from where the problem occurs. .energymaterials.org/cztse-06).. Please go to this link and drag the cif file which is found on the side of the jmol window. You will be getting the output . But why directly the jmol is not running ?

Comment: Try `[jsmol acc='caffeine' type='mol' fileurl='https://energymaterials.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/CZTSe-2x2x1.cif']`

Comment: I exhausted all the options. I did the same . Still I am not getting the output.

Comment: What could be the problem? I dont understand . Please help me.

Comment: Contact plugin author.

Comment: But I dont know who is he ? How to contact him and where do I find him?

Comment: Contact him at [GitHub](https://github.com/jimhu-tamu/wordpress) or send a tweet to @jimhu

Comment: No, I searched there . But he has not given any number or any other details. Please help me with any options to make this out . I want to display the output. Please do something. I am trying this for more than 2 months and I want it now. Please please please please

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/jimhu-tamu/wordpress/issues/1) and join the conversation at the end of page.  OR tweet to [@jimhu](https://twitter.com/jimhu)

Comment: I tweeted to the author and I also I sent a feedback .

Comment: I dont know when will he reply to my feedback.

Comment: The developer of the plugin can give better information as compared to any one here on WPSE. So wait for his reply or try to find some other plugin with same functionality. WPSE is meant for general questions related to wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is there is only one plugin for available for jmol and we have no other choice other than to rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

`[jsmol acc='caffeine' type='mol']`
Will look for an uploaded file named `caffeine.mol`. If it can't find a matching post for an uploaded attachment and `type=pdb`, it will try http://rcsb.org/pdb. If it can't find a match there either, you'll get an error message in the JSmol window.